# Grabbing a simple class name for a class defined in the interpreter

Tags: scala

I want to get a simple class name regardless if the class is defined in the interpreter or in a scala code file. You can't get a simple name from a class defined in the interpreter (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7691)). As a result, I tried to create a method that would just get the fully qualified name, split it by `.`, and grab the last string:

```
def simpleNameOf(i: AnyRef) = i.getClass.getName.split('.').last
```

However, here is when things got weird.

> scala> def simpleNameOf(i: AnyRef) = i.getClass.getName.split('.').last
>   simpleNameOf: (i: AnyRef)String
>
> scala> simpleNameOf(new Human)
>   res25: String = $read$Human
>
> scala> var h = new Human
>   h: Human = Human@fdad4ab
>
> scala> h.getClass.getName
>   res27: String = Human
>
> scala> h.getClass.getName == "Human"
>   res28: Boolean = false
>
> scala> h.getClass.getName.length
>   res29: Int = 44
>
> scala> h.getClass.getName.split('.')
>    res30: Array[String] =
>   Array($line102, $read$Human)
>
> scala> "Human".split('.')
>   res31: Array[String] = Array(Human)

So how in the heck is the string Human from `getClass.getName` **44** characters long? Where did $line102 & $read$Human come from?

This is Scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another use case for `-Yrepl-class-based`:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> classOf[Foo].getSimpleName
java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
  at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1317)
  ... 33 elided

scala> :q
$ scala -Yrepl-class-based
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> classOf[Foo].getSimpleName
res0: String = Foo
```

You can turn off the output filtering of cruft:

```
scala> $intp.isettings.unwrapStrings
res2: Boolean = true

scala> $intp.isettings.unwrapStrings = false
$intp.isettings.unwrapStrings: Boolean = false

scala> class Bar
defined class Bar

scala> classOf[Bar].getName
res3: String = $line12.$read$$iw$$iw$Bar
```

If that appeals to you.

The last question: each line is wrapped in an object (or class) generally nested deeply for easy scoping of imports from history. (If you need local block semantics, you can use braces.)  There is a line package for each line.

Update: There's a ticket for the getSimpleName problem, which is due IIRC just to the double "$$" in the mangled name.  That happens for nested objects, not for classes (in the Scala sense).

Comment: An explanation for `-Yrepl-class-based`: http://scrapcodes.tumblr.com/post/79260275559/yrepl-class-based-a-not-so-talked-about-feature-of

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan There are other behaviors solved by the switch, related to JIT.

Comment: It would be useful if could then explain how this switch solves the problem. Personally I don't really understand the solution.

Comment: My understanding is that it basically doesn't decorate the classes with the meta information the REPL needs for history / auto-complete. Thanks som-snytt